# segmentation failure while allocating memory for a 2D array in c

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, multidimensional-array, malloc

I have a function that returns all the combinations of letters possible in the alphabet with repetition in a word of length LENTH_MAX. The function returns these combinations in a 2D array call 'arr'.

Since calculating the total number of arrays is a pain because you need to calculate factorial numbers [ (n + r - 1)!/r!(n - 1)! ] I decided to increasingly reallocate memory for the arrays in 'arr' as needed.

I set a variable called capacity that determinetes the initial size of 'arr' and a constant called CAP_INCR that specifies the number of arrays for which memory will be reallocated in addition to the memory already assigned. The program compiles ok by if I set CAP_INCR to 1, so that each time a new combination is found new memory is allocated for that array, the program crushes with a Segmentation fault: 11 message, if I set CAP_INCR to 100 if finishes correctly but the output is wrong, the first combination 'a a a' is repeated twice and the last combination 'z z z' is mission.

I'd really appreciate some help. I'm a decent programer in other languages but I'm just starting with C.

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

const unsigned short LENGTH_MAX = 3; 

const char alphabet[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 

#define CAP_INCR  1 /* memory increases */ 

unsigned char* combinations(unsigned char n, unsigned char r) 
{ 
    // n  length of alphabet 
    // r  length of figures 
    unsigned int  set_counter = 0;        //counting generated sequences 

    unsigned char *vector = NULL;   //where the current figure is stored 
    unsigned char *arrTemp = NULL;    // Temporary pointer store 

    unsigned int capacity = 100; // count current size of arr 
    unsigned char *arr = (unsigned char *)malloc(capacity * r * sizeof(unsigned char)); // multidimentional array 


    vector = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * r); 


    if(vector == NULL || arr == NULL) 
    { 
        fprintf(stderr, "error: insufficient memory\n"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 


    //initialize: vector[0, ..., r - 1] are 0, ..., r - 1 
    for(int l = 0; l < r; l++) //for(int l = 0; l < r; l++) // no repetition 
        vector[l] = 0; 

    //generate all successors 
    while(1) 
    { 
        set_counter++; 

        // check is arr current capacity is enough 
        if(set_counter > capacity) 
        { // We need more memory 
            capacity += CAP_INCR; 
            arrTemp = (unsigned char *)realloc(arr, capacity * r * sizeof(unsigned char)); 
            if(!arrTemp) 
            { 
                printf("Unfortunately memory reallocation failed.\n"); 
                free(arr); 
                arr = NULL; 
                exit(0); 
            } 
            arr = arrTemp; 
        } 

        for(int x = 0; x < r; x++) { // assign a new combination to arr 
            //printf("%c ", alphabet[vector[x]]); 
            *(arr + set_counter*r + x) = vector[x]; 
        } 

        //printf("(%u)\n", set_counter); 

        int j; //index 

        //easy case, increase rightmost element 
        if(vector[r - 1] < n - 1) 
        { 
            vector[r - 1]++; 
            continue; 
        } 

        //find rightmost element to increase 
        for(j = r - 2; j >= 0; j--) { 
            if(vector[j] != n - 1) { 
                break; 
            } 
        } 

        //terminate if vector[0] == n - r 
        if(j < 0) 
            break; 

        //increase 
        vector[j]++; 

        //set right-hand elements 
        for(j += 1; j < r; j++) 
            vector[j] = vector[j - 1]; 

    } 

    return arr; 
} 



int main() { 

    unsigned char* arr = combinations(sizeof(alphabet)-1, LENGTH_MAX); 

    int c=0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 3276; i++) // 3276 is the total number of combinations 
    { 
         for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
         { 
             printf("%c ", alphabet[*(arr + i*3 + j)]); 
         } 
         printf("count: %d\n",++c); 
    } 


    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Something in the code is corrupting the heap. You'll need to look through and figure out where something may be overwritten (writing more data than was allocated for the array, for example).

Comment: You're off by 1 all over.  `set_counter` is never used at 0, only starting from 1.  And you realloc one entry too late.  I think if you move `set_counter++` from the top of the loop to the bottom, it will fix those problems.  But I only skimmed your code so I don't know if there are more bugs.

Comment: Thanks a lot JS1!! you are totally right, set_counter++ should appear until after the assignment to arr, the other error is that the condition to evaluate when to make the increase should be == or >= instead of >. Now the program runs smoothly.